# If $A$ is symmetric with eigenvalue $\lambda$ then $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^TA$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

> I am trying to show that if $A$ is symmetric and has an eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^TA$.

My thoughts:

Beginning with the definition, $A\vec{v}=\lambda\vec{v}. \tag{1}$
If $A$ is symmetric, then $A^T\vec{v}=\lambda\vec{v}. \tag{2}$
Multiplying $(2)$ with $(1)$, $$A^TA\vec{v}^2=\lambda^2\vec{v}^2\implies A^TA\vec{V}=\lambda^2\vec{V}, \ \ \text{where} \ \vec{V}=\vec{v}^2.$$
Hence $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^TA$ with corresponding eigenvector $\vec{V}$.

Comment: You can’t multply two vectors. And recall that $A^T=A$, that’s the definition of being symmetric, so you only have to work with $A$

Comment: You can not mutiply vectors

Comment: If $A$ is symmetric then $A^TA=A^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $A$ with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$. 
We then know that

\begin{equation}
Av = \lambda v \; \; \; \textrm{(i)}
\end{equation}

Since $A$ is symmetric, $A^T = A$, so
\begin{equation}
A^Tv = \lambda v \; \; \; \textrm{(ii)}
\end{equation}

Hence,

\begin{equation}
(A^TA)(v) = A^T(Av) = A^T(\lambda v) = \lambda (A^Tv) = \lambda^2 v \; \; \; \textrm{(iii)}
\end{equation}

That is, $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^TA$, as desired.